# Django: browsable api main content not updating

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, api-design

I'm overriding the `perform_update` method in `rest_framework.mixins.UpdateModelMixin`.

I added code to save data from the old object locally, but this query makes the data in the browsable api not update until I reload the page again or make another query. Interestingly, the raw data at the bottom of the page (in the editor) is actually accurate! So only the displayed data in the main content is inaccurate until page reload.

**The Culprit**

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    old_obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=serializer.data["id"]) # new code
    obj = serializer.save()
    if old_obj.status != obj.status:
        print('status changed.')
```

Can anybody tell me why the browsable api main content doesn't update but the raw data does?

**Example**

I changed the 'status' field from 'rc' to 'ts'. It is updated in the raw data but not in the main content of the page.
[image: before update]
[image: after-update]

Comment: Screenshot would help here.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll update the above with screenshots.

Comment: Post your entire `perform_update` method.

Comment: Doesn't matter for the question. If you really want it, pretend this is there: if old_obj.status != obj.status: print('something changed'). I'll write that into my post as well.